# How to integration spring MVC with web-socket html5

Tags: html, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using HTML5 Websockets with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101204/using-html5-websockets-with-spring)

i make one application like 2- way communication (server to  client & client to server.)  so i use web-socket (HTML5) and i try integration with spring MVC but not connect it . so

**how to integration spring MVC with web-socket ?**

is it possible or not possible  ? if possible , then how to ?

Please help me ...

kamlesh

Comment: Here is an update on WebSocket support in Spring Framework 4.0 M2, see http://blog.springsource.org/2013/07/24/spring-framework-4-0-m2-websocket-messaging-architectures/

Comment: @Rossen Stoyanchev : Thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring doesn't support web-sockets.

http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/08/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-techniques-for-real-time-updates/

Comment: what will do ? (Wait for web-sockets support OR use other way like long time polling ...) (i have 1-2 Months time .)

Comment: @kamlesh0606 what will do ? accept the answer then find a solution that does not rely on connecting websockets to spring.

Comment: i am use jetty Or tomcat web-sockets using servlet . and then servlet to spring call and then all code in spring ......

Comment: FWIW, It appears that spring is working on websockets for an upcoming release based on commits in their git repo at:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/tree/websocket

Comment: Spring is introducing web-socket support in Spring 4 - http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+springsource%2FOEVE+(SpringSource_News_and_Blog_Posts)